# Slick withfilter example

Tags: scala, slick

I am really new in scala and slick. For project template, i using activator and download slick template from this https://github.com/cdiniz/play-slick-rest#master. 
It provides BaseDAO class and CRUD methods. 
What makes me confuse is, there is function like this

```
def deleteByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f:  (T) => C): Future[Int] = {
      db.run(tableQ.withFilter(f).delete)
}
```

when i call the method using

```
suppliersDAO.deleteByFilter(_.name== nameValue)
```

there is no log at all, no throw exception or any message but no data were deleted.

I also trying to use the method with this

```
suppliersDAO.deleteByFilter(_.name === nameValue)
```

but the compiler said

```
 ambiguous implicit values:
 both value BooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Boolean]]
 and value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Boolean]]]
 match expected type slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
```

I've read through the documentation of slick here http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html and found the way to use the filter is with `obj.field === param`. How can i use the function? How to create a function that convert `T` (SuppliersTable) into `C` CanBeQueryCondition?

Sorry, but im being stuck for days. Dont know where to start.